# Is CV tag for "curriculum vitae" or "computer vision"?

Tags: discussion

I noted that some computer vision questions are tagged as [computer-vision](/questions/tagged/computer-vision) and [cv](/questions/tagged/cv). At the same time, some curriculum vitae questions are also tagged as [cv](/questions/tagged/cv).

What is this tag for?

We probably need to write tag wiki to clarify this.

Comment: Yes (15 characters seems precisely designed for my snarky comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a usage for [cv](/questions/tagged/cv) that doesn't deal with curricula vitae that should take precedence, as Stack Overflow isn't the place to talk about them: [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is (and technically, only under limited circumstances as defined by [its FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)).

Indeed, most of the questions in the [cv](/questions/tagged/cv) tag that relate to curricula vitae have been closed: I've voted to close the ones that aren't, but a few of them are really ancient.

Comment: It is you Editing that refers to tag "curriculum-vitae" in my initial question i have put a phrase not tags. There are 18 questions tagged as "cv"

Comment: @Ross yeah, I realized my mistake. Fixed. The questions about curriculum vitae tagged "cv" are mostly closed, as they should be since Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask those questions.

Comment: It still confuses some people. In EU and probably in some other places CV is associated with resume not computer vision.

Comment: @Ross it doesn't seem that confusion is borne out in practice. In the past year, four questions have used it for curriculum vitae and were closed. The rest related to OpenCV. In the context of Stack Overflow, there's no legitimate use of the cv tag to mean anything related to curriculum vitae, as those questions are off-topic there.

Comment: What gender is "vitae"? Could it be "curriculum vitarum"? Or "curricula vitarum"?

Comment: plural is: "curricula vitae"